# How can I solved a ParserException on an icalendar import?

Tags: java, android, icalendar, ical4j

When I want to import the save that I made of my Calendar, by using this code :

```
    public static void saveICalendarFile(String filename, Calendar object, Context context) {
        try {
            object.getProperties().add(new ProdId("-//EDT ENIB//iCal4j 1.0//EN"));
            object.getProperties().add(Version.VERSION_2_0);
            object.getProperties().add(CalScale.GREGORIAN);

            for (CalendarComponent event : object.getComponents()) {
                event.getProperty(Property.DTSTAMP).setValue((new DateTime(true).toString()));
            }
            FileOutputStream fout = null;
            try {
                Log.d("SAVE", "*************" + context.getFilesDir() + File.separator + filename);
                fout = new FileOutputStream(context.getFilesDir() + File.separator + filename);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                File file = new File(context.getFilesDir() + File.separator + filename);
                file.createNewFile();
                fout = new FileOutputStream(file);
            }

            CalendarOutputter outputter = new CalendarOutputter();
            outputter.output(object, fout);
        } catch (IOException | ParseException | URISyntaxException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static Calendar loadICalendarFile(String filename, Context context) {
        FileInputStream fin = null;
        try {
            fin = new FileInputStream(context.getFilesDir() + File.separator + filename);
            Log.d("LOAD", "*************" + context.getFilesDir() + File.separator + filename);
            Reader r = new InputStreamReader(fin, "ISO-8859-15");
            CalendarBuilder builder = new CalendarBuilder();
            Calendar calendar = builder.build(r);
            return calendar;
        } catch (IOException | ParserException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
```

It gives me back this errorstack :

```
W/System.err: net.fortuna.ical4j.data.ParserException: Error at line 5,775:null
W/System.err:     at net.fortuna.ical4j.data.CalendarParserImpl.parse(CalendarParserImpl.java:158)
W/System.err:     at net.fortuna.ical4j.data.CalendarBuilder.build(CalendarBuilder.java:183)
W/System.err:     at net.fortuna.ical4j.data.CalendarBuilder.build(CalendarBuilder.java:171)
W/System.err:     at com.enib.enibapp.Outils.iCalendarFileControler.loadICalendarFile(iCalendarFileControler.java:55)
W/System.err:     at com.enib.enibapp.AgendaActivity.onResume(AgendaActivity.java:126)
W/System.err:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1355)
W/System.err:     at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:7117)
W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3556)
W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3621)
W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2862)
W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1589)
W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
W/System.err: Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
W/System.err:     at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1450)
W/System.err:     at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupHostByName(Inet6AddressImpl.java:102)
W/System.err:     at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Inet6AddressImpl.java:90)
W/System.err:     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:787)
W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.Dns$1.lookup(Dns.java:39)
W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.resetNextInetSocketAddress(RouteSelector.java:175)
W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.nextProxy(RouteSelector.java:141)
W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.next(RouteSelector.java:83)
W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findConnection(StreamAllocation.java:174)
W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection(StreamAllocation.java:126)
W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.newStream(StreamAllocation.java:95)
W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:281)
W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:224)
W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:461)
W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:407)
W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:244)
W/System.err:     at net.fortuna.ical4j.model.TimeZoneLoader.updateDefinition(TimeZoneLoader.java:146)
W/System.err:     at net.fortuna.ical4j.model.TimeZoneLoader.loadVTimeZone(TimeZoneLoader.java:109)
W/System.err:     at net.fortuna.ical4j.model.TimeZoneRegistryImpl.getTimeZone(TimeZoneRegistryImpl.java:181)
W/System.err:     at net.fortuna.ical4j.data.DefaultContentHandler.resolveTimezones(DefaultContentHandler.java:183)
W/System.err:     at net.fortuna.ical4j.data.DefaultContentHandler.endCalendar(DefaultContentHandler.java:72)
W/System.err:     at net.fortuna.ical4j.data.CalendarParserImpl.parseCalendar(CalendarParserImpl.java:127)
W/System.err:     at net.fortuna.ical4j.data.CalendarParserImpl.parseCalendarList(CalendarParserImpl.java:180)
W/System.err:     at net.fortuna.ical4j.data.CalendarParserImpl.parse(CalendarParserImpl.java:149)
W/System.err:   ... 17 more
```

But I don't understand why I have this error because I succeeded in retieving this calendar from an online server but not in importing it in my application after saving it before the application's closing ?!

This is the format of my icalendar file :

```
    BEGIN:VCALENDAR
    BEGIN:VEVENT
    SUMMARY:Event 1
    DESCRIPTION:Professeur:NAME name \nGroupe:S5A-01_A
    DTSTART;TZID=Europe/Paris:20191211T080500
    DTEND;TZID=Europe/Paris:20191211T093500
    DTSTAMP:20200527T104154
    LOCATION:B213
    STATUS:CONFIRMED
    UID:47468078
    END:VEVENT
    .
    .
    .
    END:VCALENDAR
```

Could you help me to solve this mystery?

Comment: `Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException` you cannot execute network requests on UI thread. It is not allowed to block UI thread.

Comment: Thx @JeneaVranceanu for the clear up but how is it possible that my loadICalendarFile method is called in a UI thread? Because sometimes in my AgendaActivity, I use some runOnUiThread but not with a call to loadICalendarFile!?

Comment: Could you give a link to your icalendar file? If not, could you check what is on the line 5775 in your icalendar file? And why exactly `NetworkOnMainThreadException` occurs I do not know as I haven't see ical4j implementation yet.

Comment: Looks like ical4j is not thread-safe. After you will be able to find out with is the issue on the line 5775 in your file rewrite `loadICalendarFile` and `saveICalendarFile` to AsyncTask. Or better - coroutines, if you are familiar with Kotlin and coroutines.

Comment: Thx @JeneaVranceanu! The problem was that my iCalendarFileControler didn't extends the AsyncTask interface. At line 5775 was the END:VCALENDAR that why I was very suspicious on it!